# How to push new li with animation to list in angular/css/html

Tags: jquery, angularjs, animation, css-animations

https://jsfiddle.net/qxte54o2/6/

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="show">List item</li>
  <li class="show">List item</li>
</ul>



ul {
    width: 210px;
    /* overflow-x: scroll; */
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background: #d1703c;
  color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 10em;
}

li.show {
  height: 2em;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

Hi 
I have the following fiddle and I trying to achieve pushing li animation with loader in **Angular 1**

i did not understand how can I do it in angular way or even in jquery an then i will write a directive to wrap it.

the situation that I want to achieve is:
new data is coming : loader will appear in the right side of the scrollable list
when the data will be ready the loader will disappear and an new

will be appended by pushing the others li's  to left with small animation like
and the active li will be that new li with border or smth (at the even each li will be link to new page or new view)

I trying to use animation but it is not do the pushing

I tried to use this article :
https://cssanimation.rocks/list-items/

please help , thx a  lot

Comment: I don't understand how you want your <li> elements to be shown on the page. You speak of pushing them to left, which means you want them horizontally-  but your fiddle shows the <li> items vertically. Can you add an image or snippet of your <li> layout ?

Comment: sorry, updated the fiddle  @wick3d
yes I mean in horizontal 
https://jsfiddle.net/qxte54o2/6/